Keyboard layout change not recognized
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
I've made this change:
default partial alphanumeric_keys
// xkb_symbols "basic" {

// Existing content ...

// Add the following lines to map Right Alt + a, e, i, o, u to á, é, í, ó, ú
key <AC01> { [ a, A, aacute, Aacute ] };  // á, Á
key <AD03> { [ e, E, eacute, Eacute ] };  // é, É
key <AD08> { [ i, I, iacute, Iacute ] };  // í, Í
key <AD09> { [ o, O, oacute, Oacute ] };  // ó, Ó
key <AD07> { [ u, U, uacute, Uacute ] };  // ú, Ú

// Add mappings for additional Hungarian characters if needed
key <AC11> { [ apostrophe, quotedbl, odiaeresis, Odiaeresis ] };  // ö, Ö
key <AE11> { [ minus, underscore, udiaeresis, Udiaeresis ] };     // ü, Ü
key <AE12> { [ equal, plus, uacute, Uacute ] };                    // ű, Ű
key <AD06> { [ y, Y, udiaeresis, Udiaeresis ] };                   // ü, Ü
key <AD10> { [ p, P, odoubleacute, Odblac ] };                     // ő, Ő
};

To my /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us file.
The change do not take effect. When I press left alt with characters they are not what they are set in the settings.
